# Как получить token для получения капчи из сайта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, веб-программирование

Необходимо в *iOS* -приложении получать капчу с [сайта](https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru). Запрос на получение этой капчи выглядит следующим образом: `https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/Captcha/Generate?t=434094d8047d470db4fb792f7aa84e59`
где t -это токен. Однако в открытом виде он, кажется, нигде не передается. Каким образом его можно достать, подскажите?

PS: судя по всему, ссылка на капчу действительна только 1 раз, после чего при переходе на этот URL видно только черный квадрат вместо картинки с капчой, то есть токен должен меняться каждый раз, как я понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Там по нажатию на кнопку отправляется POST-запрос на `https://www.reestr-zalogov.ru/Captcha/Init`, без каких-либо параметров, и с пустым телом.

А ответом сервер присылает JSON, со ссылкой на картинку капчи с токеном, плюс токен отдельно:

```
{
    "HasError" : false,
    "ImageUrl" : "/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef",
    "Token" : "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef"
}
```